# Why isn't localhost resolving but other host entries are?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-7, proxy

I have a Windows 7 machine that I am working on right now and am having trouble connecting to a local server that is bound to 0.0.0.0:1337

On all the other machines that run this configuration it works fine.

The machine connects to the internet via a proxy configured in the windows Internet Options settings. I currently have the checkbox ticked that says "Bypass proxy for local addresses"

Once I have the service running I am attempting to load it via Chrome. Normally http://127.0.0.1:1337 will work, but it appears that it is trying to resolve through the proxy, the same goes if I try http://localhost:1337.

For testing purposes I added
    127.0.0.1 appname
to the hosts file. If I open chrome and load http://appname:1337 it works.

This problem doesn't make any sense to me. What could be causing this?

Edit:
If I attempt to load http://localhost without the port number it appears to resolve locally, but if I try to load http://localhost:1337 it attempts to resolve through the proxy.

Update: I can load the application in IE but not Chrome. Chrome is trying to send it through the proxy. I need it to load in Chrome as the application is in NW.js

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by explicitly setting `127.0.0.1 localhost` in the hosts file then clearing Chrome's cache.

After this the page started loading as expected.

I believe this was an isolated incident pertaining to the specific proxy server that the computer is connected through.